# Knockout Mapping: JSON grows when mapping and saving multiple times

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

When I take a knockout object and serialize it to JSON by doing ko.toJSON, and then unserialize it from JSON using ko.mapping.fromJSON multiple times, the loaded object has this `__ko_mapping__` property that recursively grows.

Sample code:

```
var joe = new Person();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var json = ko.toJSON(joe);
    joe = ko.mapping.fromJSON(json);
}
```

Simple JSFiddle that reproduces it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gc89Q/1/

How can I load and save multiple times without having the serialized json form grow to be gigantic?

I was considering just setting the `__ko_mapping__` property to undefined when loading, but am wondering if there is a better way or something I am missing.

Is this a bug I file an issue for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overwrite the model. Instead, pass it to `fromJSON` so the model is updated:

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(json, joe);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gc89Q/2/

Comment: So in my actual use case I load and save the JSON to html5 localStorage between page loads.

When I load the page for the first time should I first create a new blank person, and then pass that in as the 2nd parameter to `ko.mapping.fromJSON`, instead of ever using the 1 argument `fromJSON`?

Comment: If you create a new blank person, pass 1 argument: `var joe = ko.mapping.fromJSON(json)` (or `fromJS` if it's a plain JS object). Then if you want to update that person afterwards, use 2 arguments like above.